# External .war In play framework

Tags: playframework, sbt, quartz-scheduler

I have a play application which uses Quartz scheduler and I am trying to set UI monitoring for the scheduled jobs.

I'm running the application server using sbt - > start

I was able to deploy [jwatch](https://code.google.com/p/jwatch/) (Quartz monitor) on a different tomcat server but i would like to integrate the .war file jwatch supplies in the same server play framework uses.
How can it be done ?

Comment: Maybe this can be done on build.sbt file of the playframework project ?

Answer (score 0):

As the Play Framework isn't a servlet container, it's not going to be possible to just feed it a WAR file.

There's a few things you could try:

1. Reaching out to the JWatch maintainers about what you're trying to do
2. Consider if you want to export your Play app as a WAR (see [play2-war-plugin](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin)) and run it in the same servlet container (eg. Tomcat)
3. Consider looking into alternatives to JWatch